# python - rglob exclude pattern inside starmap

Tags: python

i'm trying to use script from this open source project: https://github.com/Eloston/ungoogled-chromium/blob/master/devutils/update_lists.py, what it does is scanning recursively chromium source directory to find domain names, below code is doing that job

```
# Launch multiple processes iterating over the source tree
with Pool(processes) as procpool:
    returned_data = procpool.starmap(
        compute_lists_proc,
        zip(source_tree.rglob('*'), repeat(source_tree), repeat(search_regex)))
```

and the script assumes the source code is downloaded and extract from tar file, so it doesn't have `.git` dirs inside,

but i already have chromium source code cloned using `git`, and google `gclient` tool, and my source code has multiple `.git` dirs inside, as you know, the chromium source is very big, i don't want to download it again, so i wanted to modify the script to make it work for my local chromium source.

here's the problem, if not excluding `.git` dirs, the script will work on those `.pack` files inside `.git` dir, and crash with error like this:

```
INFO: Using existing source tree at /path/to/chromium/src
INFO: Computing lists...
ERROR: Unhandled exception while processing .git/objects/pack/pack-5582c833efb8d8fe08cc194ce33fdf372b9e495f.pack
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "./devutils/update_lists.py", line 268, in compute_lists_proc
    if should_prune(path, relative_path, used_pep_set, used_pip_set):
  File "./devutils/update_lists.py", line 193, in should_prune
    if _is_binary(file_obj.read()):
  File "./devutils/update_lists.py", line 156, in _is_binary
    return bool(bytes_data.translate(None, _TEXTCHARS))
MemoryError
```

so i updated script like this:

```
# Launch multiple processes iterating over the source tree
with Pool(processes) as procpool:
    returned_data = procpool.starmap(
        compute_lists_proc,
        zip(source_tree.rglob('[!.git]*'), repeat(source_tree), repeat(search_regex)))
```

but the exclude pattern doesn't work, script will crash with same error message...

so how can i exclude `.git` dirs while recusively scanning directory?

thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not sure if it can be done with the `globe`. You can use a filter instead.

```py
with Pool(processes) as procpool:
    returned_data = procpool.starmap(
        compute_lists_proc,
        zip(filter(lambda x: ".git" not in x.parts, source_tree.rglob('*')), repeat(source_tree), repeat(search_regex)))
```